# Download file via php using cronjob

Tags: php, unix, cron

I want to download a JSON file from an URL every 2 days and I was thinking to do it with PHP
in my script.php I've written a very simple thing

```
<?php

function getRepo()
{
    file_put_contents("repo.json", file_get_contents('http://somesite.com/repo.json'));
}

getRepo();
```

This is fully functional if I try it in browser
Now I'm tring to automate it

I've done

```
crontab -e
```

and added

```
PATH=/usr/bin # refers to where php executable is
10 * * * * php /path/to/my/script.php
```

this should run every 10 min just to see if working, but it doesn't and I don't understand why...

Comment: It shoud run 10 minuts after full hour (1:10, 2:10 etc.). Use `*/10`

Comment: to make it run every 10 mins you would have to say `0,10,20,30,40,50 * * * * php /path/to/my/script.php`

Comment: You can use @Orangepill version or `*/10 * * * * php /path/to/my/script.php`. And look out for `* * */2 * *` - it means "_every 2 days and every minutes in that day_". Use `0 10 */2 * *` as "_every 2 days at 10:00_".

Comment: @furas awesome... I was trying to figure out how you would do every other day...

Comment: Ok resolved the time problem thx @furas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you just want the file and not do any processing of it just use wget

```
wget http://somesite.com/repo.json
```

do a search on wget for its options of saving to specific file location forget what they are atm.

Comment: Used curl now with 
   `curl --silent -o OutputFilename URL`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

    

`function getRepo()
{
    file_put_contents("/path/to/my/repo.json", file_get_contents('http://somesite.com/repo.json'));
}

 getRepo();`

When scripts run on cron, you must defined full path when script save the json("/path/to/my/").
In cron for 10 minutes, try */10